# html5 audio hide download button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-audio

I Use the code below to play .mp3 files in a company portal (asp.net webform).

```
 <audio id="player" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px" src="audio/aaa.mp3" controls loop autoplay></audio>
```

Everything works fine, but when I use chrome a download button is visible within the audio controls.

[audio download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmi8d.png)

How can I hide or disable the download button, without disable the other controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google added a new feature since chrome 58. Now you can do this :

```
<audio width="400" height="38" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source data-src="...." type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

More info here

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-media-updates#controlslist

Answer (score 3):

I have run into the same issue, where I want the convenience of the native audio element but have business requirements where I don't want to show the new Chrome download button.

I made a hacky solution where I position a masking div over the download button to hide it, if I detect Chrome 55 or above.

```
<div id="player">
  <audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Fur_Elise.ogg" controls></audio>
  <div id="mask"></div>
</div>

<style media="screen">
#player {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
#mask {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F3F5F6; /* match the background color of the page */
  position: absolute;
  width: 34px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var match = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)/);
  if (match && parseInt(match[1]) >= 55) {
    document.getElementById('mask').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/keeth/bqdc4uL7/6/

Comment: I think a small modification should be made to this code:
background-color: #fafafa;

Answer (score 1):

This can hide download button on Chrome when HTML5 Audio is used.

```css
 #aPlayer > audio { width: 100% }
        /* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
       /* HIDE DOWNLOAD AUDIO BUTTON */
     #aPlayer {
           overflow: hidden;width: 390px; 
        }

    #aPlayer > audio { width: 420px; }
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    
      #aPlayer {
           overflow: hidden;width: 390px; 
        }

    #aPlayer > audio { width: 420px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="aPlayer">
 <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2012.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
 </audio>
</div>
```

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SowdI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #aPlayer > audio { width: 100% }
        /* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
       /* HIDE DOWNLOAD AUDIO BUTTON */
     #aPlayer {
           overflow: hidden;width: 390px; 
        }

    #aPlayer > audio { width: 420px; }
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    
      #aPlayer {
           overflow: hidden;width: 390px; 
        }

    #aPlayer > audio { width: 420px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="aPlayer">
 <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2012.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
 </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this syntax

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio/aaa.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I try this on Chrome and works fine. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all).

Comment: the download button is still present... my need is to disable it.

Comment: Which Chrome version are using you?

Comment: Version 55.0.2883.75 m. I think is the latest.